# Vue.js 2.0 For "admissions is not defined"

Tags: vue.js

I'm having an error on this vue.js 2.0 .

My HTML CODE

```
<div id="app">
     <select class="form-control input-lg" name="admission_id" >
                                    <option>Select Admission type</option>
                                    <option v-for="admission in admissions">@{{ admission.message}}</option>
                                </select>
</div>
```

My vue.js

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        admissions: [
            { message: 'Foo' },
            { message: 'Bar' }
        ]


    }
});
```

This is the error. As you can see I did defined the admissions and display it, however there is an error. BTW I'm newbie on this Vue.js
[image]

Comment: Show us the html of `#app`

Comment: I updated the the div id="app"

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/rjcb88f0/

Comment: Thanks I have figured it out... I used the built-n laravel app.js. Sigh... Got some errors but I separated and downloaded the vue.js. and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reference for people who will find this question in the future.

Author was using build-in Laravel app.js which is common issue of Laravel's users. (the answer is in the comment under the question)

Always remember to include VueJS one time and only one time.

If you are using some bundling software like Webpack/Browserify - DO NOT INCLUDE VueJS separately in your html, as it is already bundled with your code.